# Cannot log in to Firebase and the NPM installation gives out errors npm ERR! code ENOTSUP

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

The following errors are shown in NPM installation log,

```
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /System/Volumes/Data/home/package-lock.json
npm ERR! errno -45
npm ERR! ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, open '/System/Volumes/Data/home/package-lock.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2022-06-27T14_25_01_647Z-debug-0.log
username@usernames-MacBook-Air-2 /home % npm audit fix
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2022-06-27T14_25_08_669Z-debug-0.log
```

I followed the documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) and I encounter the following error when i try to execute,

```
source ~/.profile

/Users/username/.profile:1: permission denied: /usr/local/bin
```

I added the location /usr/local/bin into the ~/.bash_profile.

Still there is no luck. When I open the above .profile file on vi editor i see that its empty.

I am new to Firebase and NodeJS so excuse the beginner question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same and managed to resolve this by using curl to install.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-mac-linux